# Mono.flatMap is not getting invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am still new to Spring Webflux and flatMap on Mono doesn't seem to work.
 I have the following function and call to *kafkaPublisher.publishToTopic* is not working. I inserted the print statement to test if it prints anything and it doesn't even execute the print statement. *publishToTopic* returns `Mono<Void>`.

```
private Mono<Void> test(Long gId, UUID pId) {
    Mono<UUID> nId = pDao.findNId(pId);
    Mono<List<String>> channels = nId.flatMapMany(pDao::findChannels).collectList();
    return Mono.zip(nId, channels)
           .flatMap(t -> {
               System.out.println(t.getT1());
               return kafkaPublisher.publishToTopic(gId, t.getT1().toString(), t.getT2());
           });
```

}

It gets invoked if `.block` is called on `flatMap` as shown below.

```
private Mono<Void> test(Long gId, UUID pId) {
    Mono<UUID> nId = pDao.findNId(pId);
    Mono<List<String>> channels = nId.flatMapMany(pDao::findChannels).collectList();
    Mono.zip(nId, channels)
           .flatMap(t -> {
               System.out.println(t.getT1());
               return kafkaPublisher.publishToTopic(gId, t.getT1().toString(), t.getT2());
           }).block();
    return Mono.empty();
```

}

Comment: Haven't used Webflux before, but if  `Mono` is supposed to be asynchronous (ie similar to a `Future`) then what you're seeing isn't surprising. To guarantee that an async construct has done its work by a certain point you need to block on it manually at that point. Probably in the framework itself you're supposed to pass or return the Mono to something that will handle it rather than blocking on it manually.

Comment: how are you calling that initial `test` method? Could you show a code snippet? Could you also add `log()` operators after `findNId` and `flatMap` and share the logs here?

Comment: @Ryan No, you shouldn't `block` on reactive types and `Future` are very different - you can read about that in the reference documentation here: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_asynchronicity_to_the_rescue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake. I wasn't not using the result of `test` anywhere in the function where I was calling this `test` method. Here is the code I was using to call `test`

```
public Mono<Void> saveNew(NewPre pre) {
    preDao.insert(pre)
                        .flatMap(p -> test(p.pId(), p.nId()));
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

I changed it to following and it works.

```
public Mono<Void> saveNew(NewPre pre) {
    return preDao.insert(preference)
                        .flatMap(p -> test(p.p(), p.n())
                            .then(Mono.empty()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

flatMap hangs indefinitely, Best way to close the Asynchronous operation by converting it into future object .

```
public Mono<Void> saveNew(NewPre pre) {
return preDao.insert(preference)
                    .flatMap({
                       p -> test(p.p(), p.n())
                      
                    }).toFuture();
}
```